# How to Remove Duplicate Libraries added via gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am using two libraries in my project. One is [this](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/) and the other is [this](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText).

Whenever I run the App with Edit Test library it shows **UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION**:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    E:\Android\me\me\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Project\RemoteiT\RemoteiT\mobile\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Project\RemoteiT\RemoteiT\mobile\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I Assume that the above error shows that `com.nineoldandroids` is added twice or conflicting.

So I tried to remove it in the build.gradle file. But it is still showing the error!

Is my Assumption is right? Or elsewhere did I go wrong?

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.aruhan.remt"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    // to avoid double inclusion of support libraries
    all*.exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'materialDesign'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile project(':materialDesign')
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.7.1'
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of adding it in the Configurations. I added the exclude for only the library like this:

```
compile ('com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.7.1') {
   exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > project structure > Inside module select your > click on Dependencies on right hand side and see there are duplicate libraries are present or not?

Also try invalidate/Restart cache

Answer (score 0):

If the error occurring due to duplication of libraries you can use packagingOptions in build.gradle file.

```
android {
  ....
  packagingOptions {
    exclude '.....'
    pickFirst '.....'
  }
}
```