# Multiple dex files define: when I am adding admob. this is due to ActionbarSherlock Lib

Tags: android

When I am adding admob to gradle file,I am getting "**com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;"**. This is happening because of **ActionBarSherlock** lib. After searching on google, some people suggested to remove **support v4 jar** file.But this solution is also not working. Please help me out to get the solution.

**EDIT**

My Gradle File:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.4-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.8.3.jar')
    compile project(':CustomTabLib')
    compile project(':simple-crop-image-lib')
    compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-7.0.7.jar')
    compile project(':ActionbarSherlockLibrary')
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
//    dexOptions {
//        preDexLibraries = false
//    }

}
```

I have edited my question @Destro.

Comment: Are you added any annotation jar?

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I didn't added annotation jar. I am getting this error because of ActionbarSherlock Lib. But not able to find the solution.

Comment: show me girdle file code..

Comment: then check there is annotation jar is available or not

Comment: @user3676184 do u mean in my code?

Comment: please check annotation jar in all project if it's available then remove it

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719436/how-to-remove-duplicate-libraries-added-via-gradle

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project ?

Comment: Yes many times i cleaned the project @Nilesh Jarad

Answer (score 0):

Try this If you're having a dependency conflict with the v4 support library, you can just exclude it from one of the libraries via the gradle script:

e.g

```
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: But how do i exclude "google-play-service" from ActionbarSherlock library  ?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175740/actionbarsherlock-dependency-issue-after-updating-support-libraries